# Client login form for a Spring Security OAuth2 server

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, frontend

I have a microservice architecture with a server oauth2 and zuul.
All connections must be autentified.
My services work with postman, but I can not find a good tutorial to make a login form on my front.
I use spring / thymeleaf in front.

Do you know one?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have find response on internet ...

I use [Spring Security](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) configuration and i create a route form login return jwt token.

on others route check if you have Authorization : TOKEN.

On your front-end after login add your token on headers of all requests to the Spring server.

Sorry for me English.

Comment: but my problem is : how create a login form with java/spring to send username/password and grant = password ?

Comment: many tutorial create login on the authorization server (you can use a client in thymeleaf): https://github.com/Akourtiim/oauth2-spring-boot-2.0.2 https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth some otherwise you can call directly the authorization server with a ajax request.